# Uppercase letters first in exec sort

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I am doing an exercise where I must pass a file into a pipe sort the file with exec sort and print it . 
My problem is that the results are not exactly as I want them .
My Infile Data is this .

```
abcdefg
123456
XXXXXX
01010101
```

When I call `execlp("sort", "sort",(char *)0);` and I read the pipe I get this as an output :

```
01010101
123456
abcdefg
XXXXXX
```

I actually want this to be printed :

```
01010101
123456
XXXXXX
abcdefg
```

I have to somehow tell `Sort` that I want uppercase characters to be shown first . Which is the correct statement for the `execlp("sort", "sort",(char *)0);`?

Comment: You need to set the `LC_COLLATE` environment variable to `"C"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! Do I write that in my main() function ? Can you give me an example ?

Comment: Read the documentation of the `putenv()` function.

Comment: Rather than use `putenv()`, you should look at [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html), and you may need to use
[`unsetenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unsetenv.html) afterwards to undo the change.  And use `getenv()` of course to check whether `LC_COLLATE` is already set.  You could consider `execve()` or `execvpe()` (if you have the latter) too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `LC_COLLATE` environment variable to `"C"`.

Read the documentation of the `putenv()` function.
                    – Barmar

Rather than use `putenv()`, you should look at `setenv()`, and you may need to use `unsetenv()` afterwards to undo the change.  And use `getenv()` of course to check whether `LC_COLLATE` is already set.  You could consider `execve()` or `execvpe()` (if you have the latter) too.
                    – Jonathan Leffler